# React Input Component is not editable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, z-index

The problem: my `<input>` is not editable. I am using React with Next, have a simple login form with just one `<input>` element of type="email", which has been working fine until I moved it to a modal window.

So, in order to not trigger the "potential duplicate to...", let me summarize what I've tried so far:

1. Verified that I have the correct casing for my onChange event handler.
2. Also researched the topic on dealing with z-index on components using it, but it mentions issues with negative z-index, and nothing about positive values.
3. Have looked into 15+ topics on SO for this exact problem — most of them were focusing on proper casing for the `onChange` event handler or trying to use `defaultValue` in place of `value`.

Damn, I think I have tried everything I could find on SO, but am still stuck at the issue of not being able to feed any input from my keyboard (however, all of my autocomplete options make their way into the input field and do trigger the handler).

Here is the simplified code for my "problem" component (removed styling and unnecessary code):

```
import React from "react";

class Login extends React.Component {

state = {login: ""}

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleLoginType = this.handleLoginType.bind(this);
  }

  handleLoginType(event) {
    this.setState({ login: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    // handle submit routine
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Aux>
       <div id="backdrop"></div>
       <div id="loginForm">
          <article>
           <p>Access your account</p>
           <div>
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
                   <input onChange={this.handleLoginType} 
                          name="login"
                          id="loginEmail"
                          type="email"
                          value={this.state.login}
                    />
                   <button type="submit">Log in</button>
              </form>
          </article>
        </div>
      </Aux>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

This component has a CSS style that has z-index of 100, and the backdrop has z-index set to 50.

---

**Added CodeSandBox Example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-ellis-bjh8f?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: This code works for me if I add `props` to the `constructor` and `super` functions. My guess is it has something to do with the way `Login` is rendered. It might be unmounting/re-mounting when it should be re-rendering? I can't say without a working example of the problem.

Comment: Not saying this is the issue in this specific case, but typically, setting the `value` prop directly as opposed to `defaultValue` will make your input read-only.

Comment: @codemonkey That's only if you don't provide a `onChange` function that can update the `value` provided.

Comment: I have moved ```this.state={login:""}``` to the constructor function, but it didn't help. Tampering with the `defaultValue` had no success. I will try to create a sample sandbox example.

Comment: @BrianThompson If I may, how would `onChange` even get triggered if you can't modify the input? What am I missing here: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-vaughan-x0qnu?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Also, I am not encountering any errors or warnings in my console.

Comment: The ```onChange``` event is triggered if I click in the ```input``` field and then select one of my previously saved inputs from AutoComplete.

Comment: @codemonkey `input` handles the function call internally. Change your handler to console.log or alert `e.target.value`, it does get called with the *potential* next value. However, assigning a new value to `e.target.value` is incorrect, so you will not see an update.

Comment: Here is a working example of your code https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-banzai-utqxv. The problem is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Here is the codesandbox example with the behavior I was able to reproduce: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-ellis-bjh8f?file=/src/App.js

Comment: In the app.js, you added a event listener, where you are preventing the default behaviour, comment line no 31 in app.js and try " event.preventDefault();"

Comment: Why did you hardcode an empty string for the value in the sandbox? That definitely won't work.

Comment: check the updated code here which is working -  
https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-lovelace-mcdqz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the updated code here which is working -
http://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-lovelace-mcdqz

In the app.js, you added a event listener, where you are preventing the default behaviour, comment line no 31(event.preventDefault();) in app.js and try

As you added the keypressed event to the document and preventing the default behaviour keypressed, input onchange event is not getting triggered. check event phases here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/eventPhase

Comment: I was focusing on finding issues in the component itself and didn't look at outer code, even when posting to codesandbox -- my fault.